# Finding synonymous alliterations

Tags: discussion, online-resources

Any recommendations on an online alliteration generator that searches through synonyms of two (or more) given words? That seems to have been how [Something of something alliteration generator](https://gdorn.circuitlocution.com/somethingofsomething.php) worked, but no longer. I see no option in *[Alliteration Applications](https://alliteration.me/index.html)*, seemingly the most developed and best known online alliteration generator, to do that either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You might get some benefit from the [software and database](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) on my website. It's not a generator, but it's sorted. Runs on DOS, Pascal source code and compiler included. It generates lists that can be analyzed semantically, like [KL-](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf), [BL-](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/bl.pdf), or [SL-](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/sl.pdf).

Comment: I wouldn't see that there'd be much use for that since whenever you use a thesaurus, the synonyms are alphabetized, so you can very readily see what synonyms start with a certain sound grouped together for you.